How to reclaim the space space used on a Verbatim USB drive that had V-Safe software on it?
I have an old Verbatim USB hard drive that had some V-Safe 100 software on it. The total size of the drive is 8 GB. When I plug in the drive, I can access about 700 MB of space. Then when I run the V-Safe software and enter a password, I could access the full 8 GB including any files I saved under the "secure" partition.
I recently backed up everything from the hard drive and then reformatted it so I can use it for other purposes. That reformat removed the V-Safe 100 software. When I plug in my drive, I only see 700 MB of space available. I cannot find the old V-Safe 100 software anywhere online, and Verbatim has not been responding to my emails through their support channels.
I've tried to reclaim the space on Windows disk management, but it doesn't show any other partitions. I also ran a live USB of Linux Mint and was not able to find any available space or partitions on the drive. But clearly there's something hidden since the drive is 8 GB.
What else can I try to reclaim the remaining space? I would like to reclaim the space and reformat it as FAT32 so that it serves as a regular USB without any of the encryption or hidden partitions.

https://gparted.org/ I have faith that gparted can see that partition.


Remove all partitions, making the drive unallocated space. 2. Commit that action -- it might not be done until you press a "Save Changes" button or similar. 3. Create a single partition for the whole drive and format (likely FAT32).


Hello @JayCravens, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately even gparted could not see the other partition. It only lists the 700 MB partition. I think as Hannu mentioned, there is a hardware component protecting it.

As @Hannu mentioned, there is firmware on the USB drive that restricts access to the partitions. I came across this post which explains how the USB drive works in more detail.
Fortunately, that post also included a link to the old V-Safe 100.exe hosted on Verbatim's website. I downloaded it, copied it onto the USB drive, and ran it. Using the software, I formatted the drive by allocating 0 MB to the Privacy Zone (see image below). That allowed me to access the contents of the entire drive.
For convenience, here's a link to download the V-Safe 100 software from that post: http://www.verbatim.com/includes/binary_details.php3?show=1&id=2960

After doing that, I was able to access the rest of the drive.

https://www.verbatim.com/UserFiles/File/V-Safe100_English.pdf
1. INTRODUCTION
...
The combination of enhanced hardware with a high-speed USB 2.0  
interface enables you to start working immediately, and to easily
secure all your confidential data

I'd say that; if nothing else helps, try using dd to write zero:s to large enough portion to blank out any present info.
BUT the mention of "enhanced hardware" above makes me wonder if that will do any good for this device.
Those 7+GB might simply be hidden in such a way that only the V-Safe software knows how to access it.

Hi @Hannu, thank you for your response! It seems I was able to use dd to write zeroes to the drive up to about 5.6 GB. However, even after that, I'm not able to read a larger portion of the drive using gparted or anything else. It seems my only solution is to (somehow) get the old version of the V-Safe 100 software.

Well, I can't say I'm surprised. Good luck.
